# How to set an instance variable within a decorator?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a class which calculates salary components as shown below.

```
def normalize(func):
    from functools import wraps

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(instance, *args, **kwargs):
        allowanceToCheck = func(instance)
        if instance.remainingAmount <= 0:
            allowanceToCheck = 0.0
        elif allowanceToCheck > instance.remainingAmount:
            allowanceToCheck = instance.remainingAmount
        instance.remainingAmount = instance.remainingAmount - allowanceToCheck
        return allowanceToCheck
    return wrapper

class SalaryBreakUpRule(object):
    grossPay = 0.0
    remainingAmount = 0.0

    @property
    def basic(self):
     # calculates the basic pay according to predefined salary slabs.
     basic = 6600 # Defaulting to 6600 for now.
     self.remainingAmount = self.grossPay - basic
     return basic

    @property
    @normalize
    def dearnessAllowance(self):
      return self.basic * 0.2

    @property
    @normalize
    def houseRentAllowance(self):
      return self.basic * 0.4

   def calculateBreakUps(self, value = 0.0):
    self.grossPay = value
    return {
        'basic' : self.basic,
        'da' : self.dearnessAllowance,
        'hra' : self.houseRentAllowance
    }
```

Before calculating each allowance, I need to check if the total of all allowances does not exceed the grossPay i.e my total salary. I have written a decorator which wraps each allowance calculating method and does the above said requirement. For example,

```
* an employee having a salary of Rs.6700
* basic = 6,600 (according to slab)
* dearnessAllowance = 100 (cos 20% of basic is more than remaining amount)
* houseRentAllowance = 0.0 (cos 40% of basic is more than remaining amount)
```

But unfortunately it did not work. First allowance is calculated correctly, but all other allowances are being given the same value as first allowance. i.e houseRentAllowance will have 100 instead of 0.0 as given above.

The problem I have found is, the line of code

```
instance.remainingAmount = instance.remainingAmount - allowanceToCheck
```

in the decorator where I am trying to set a variable of the class does not work.

Is there any way I can fix this issue?

Comment: very strange, it works for me. Do You really try to set a variable of the class or instance variable?

Comment: Hi @oleg. I believe its an instance variable.

Comment: This is not your actual code. (`Class` for `class`). Please post a runnable example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Hi @JanneKarila sorry for that typo. I have corrected it. now you can run like SalaryBreakUpRule().calculateBreakUps(value = 6700).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've made `Salary.basic` into a property, and `Salary.basic()` has side effects! So every time your other functions reference `self.basic`, it recalculates and resets `self.RemainingAmount` to its original value, `self.grossPay - basic`.

Properties with this kind of side effects are **bad design**. I hope you see why now. Even after you fix this, accessing your other properties in different order will give you different results. Property accessors should not have durable side effects. More generally: **Setters must set, getters must get.** Properties *look* like simple variables, so they must behave accordingly or you'll never be able to understand or debug your code again.

Comment: Yeah that should have been the problem I guess. Let me take a look and keep you posted. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Making `basic` into a regular variable should fix this bug, but you should discard the rest of your properties as well. Change them into actions (`deductHouseRentAllowance()`, etc.)